# How to delete multiple images from photos app selected by ELCImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, elcimagepickercontroller

I use `ELCImagePickerController` for select multiple images from photos app in my application.
I want to delete those images from photos app selected by `ELCImagePickerController`.
Please help me to solve this.

`ELCImagePickerController` allowed two methods.

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info;
- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Using `PHAssetChangeRequest`

For my project I used this, and it is in swift, but I hope this will give you the right idea. This works perfectly for me:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
      PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(photoAssets)
      }, completionHandler: { success, error in
      NSLog("Completed deletion of asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error!)) 
})
```

You would want to implement this in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Hopefully this helps.